# Writing to the end of a file if two things don't match

Tags: c#

```
        counter = 0;
        string line;
        bool validCheck = true;


        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(deckFile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && validCheck == true)
        {
            if (line.Split(',')[1] == Form1.tempUsernameOut)
            {
                validCheck = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    int lineCountDecks = File.ReadAllLines(deckFile).Length + 1; // Makes the variable set to the amount of lines in the deck file + 1.
                    string deckWriting = lineCountDecks.ToString() + "," + Form1.tempUsernameOut + ",1,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,"; // Stores what will be written in the deck file in a variable.
                    // Writes the contents of the variable "deckWriting" in the deck file.
                    StreamWriter writeFile = File.AppendText(deckFile);
                    writeFile.WriteLine(deckWriting);
                    writeFile.Close();

                    validCheck = false;
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
```

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. Here is what I am trying to do. If the second section of the first line in a text file matches tempUsernameOut, do nothing. If it doesn't match, check the next line. After checking all lines, if the second section of any line doesn't match tempUsernameOut, write the line stored in deckWriting to the end of the text file.
I got the base of the code from here. Thanks!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Awesome description `but it doesn't work`. Would you mind giving us a detailed description of what does not work exactly?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy If the text file is empty, the "if" statement does not get wrote into the text file (this is the first problem). I then manually added a line into the text file. If tempUsernameOut matches the second section of that line, the form loads fine, but if tempUsernameOut doesn't match the second section of that line, [this error](https://gyazo.com/96b14f0d8a6ba0cc9289e05de295d4f0) is shown.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Got it to work now. :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, always use "using" with streams. This way you'll be sure stream is closed even if an exception is arised.

Your issue is in that you try to write to the file when it's blocked by reading stream.
Use bool variable for checking whether you need to write to the file or not, and open stream for writing when you've closed reading stream, something like this

```
var counter = 0;
string line;
bool validCheck = true;


        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(deckFile))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && validCheck == true)
            {
                if (line.Split(',')[1] == Form1.tempUsernameOut)
                {
                    validCheck = false;
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (validCheck)
        {
            int lineCountDecks = File.ReadAllLines(deckFile).Length + 1;
            // Makes the variable set to the amount of lines in the deck file + 1.
            string deckWriting = lineCountDecks.ToString() + "," + Form1.tempUsernameOut +
                                 ",1,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,";
            // Stores what will be written in the deck file in a variable.
            // Writes the contents of the variable "deckWriting" in the deck file.
            using (var writeFile = File.AppendText(deckFile))
            {
                writeFile.WriteLine(deckWriting);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Better with _File.AppendAllText(deckFile, deckWriting);_

Comment: Thanks! Used [something very similar](https://gyazo.com/d033c662f4b3690598aa0248e4fd6674) to this (just a few changes with stuff I am more used to). I don't see how counter was ever used though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using FileStream.  Something like this:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\\path\\to\\file", FileAccess.Write)
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)
{
    sw.WriteLine(deckWriting);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more appropriate way to do it:

```
    counter = 0;
    string line;
    bool validCheck = true;


    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using( StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(deckFile) )
    {
        while(!reader.EndOfStream && validCheck == true)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.Split(',')[1] == Form1.tempUsernameOut)
            {
                validCheck = false;
            }

            counter++; //Already holds number of lines
        }
    }

    if(validCheck)
    {
        using( StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(deckFile) )
        {
            string deckWriting = string.Format("{0},{1},1,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,3,,,,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,,,,,,5,,,,,,,,,,,", counter, Form1.tempUsernameOut);
            writer.WriteLine(deckWriting);
        }
    }
```

Some comments:

1. Use the using close, so your file "handle" will be closed after you finished using it.
2. Append your line only if validCheck is still true.
3. counter already holds the number of lines.
4. string.Format looks much prettier

Comment: Thanks! Used something very similar to this (just a few changes with stuff I am more used to). I don't see how counter was ever used though.